# SQL - update returns 0 rows affect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm running an SQL script to update a certain column in a table but it is returning '(0 row(s) affected)'. If I run a similar `SELECT` script, it returns 3680 rows.

Why might this be? What am I doing wrong?

update:

```
update records set active = 0

(0 row(s) affected)
```

select:

```
select * from records where active = 1

3687 rows
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Is there an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger defined on the table?

Comment: Is `records` actually a view?

Comment: my bad, its SQL server

Comment: records is the name of the table

Comment: Are you executing the UPDATE and SELECT statements against  different databases?

Comment: Definitely on the same database :/ only one database on the server.

Comment: Write the name of the schema in both queries (when no schema is written, the default for each user is used and might be different).

Comment: when you look at the records after the update - are they updated? I.e. are you confused by the message or are the updates really not having any effect?

Comment: I'm confused by the updates not having any effect. Why would select return 3000+ rows but update not effect any of these rows.

Comment: @PaulAlexander You haven't answered Damien_The_Unbeliever 's question about a trigger.